# What does the backslash mean in this specific set, $\mathbb{R^2} ∖ {(x,0): x ≤ 0}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation

I know this is probably really trivial, but I am not sure whether the exclusion only applies to $x$ where $x$ has to be $≤$ 0. Or does it apply to not only $x$ but also $y$, where $y$ cannot be 0. I assume if we want to restrict $x$ only, it would be $\mathbb{R^2} ∖  {(x,y): x ≤ 0}$, would that be correct?

Comment: Specifically, it means $\mathbb{R}^2$ without the branch $(x \leq 0,0)$.  So, you are only excluding a half-line from the plane.

Comment: The $\setminus$ is simply set differences.  $A\setminus B$ is the set of all elements of $A$ which are not also elements of $B$.  Now... the set $\{(x,0)\color{grey}{\in\Bbb R^2}~:~x\leq 0\}$ is the set of all ordered pairs of real numbers where the first entry is non-positive and the second entry is zero.  Compare this to $\{(x,y)~:~x\leq 0\}$ which is the set of all ordered pairs where the first entry is non-positive and no restriction on the second entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$, but excluding all points where the second coordinate is zero and the first coordinate if less than or equal to zero. So it's the whole plane, but the left side of the $x$-axis (including the origin) is missing.